# Need results of query to be put in a List<Product>

Tags: c#, ado.net

How can I get the results of the query below into a `List<Product>` type?
Just want to return some results and assign it to the products variable :

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(LOCAL))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Sku from product";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) // ????
        {
            // ??????????
        }
    }
}

var products = new List<Product>();
```

I need the `products` variable to contain the results. How can this be done?

Comment: What is the structure of `Product` class, does it have just one property SKU ?

Comment: No. I has about 20 fields.

Comment: you are only selecting `SKU` in your query.

Comment: thanks all, tried the solutions but no records are being returned. Not sure why at this point.

Comment: Maybe you want to change "select Sku from product" to "select * from product"?

Answer (score 3):

Create the list before calling the database and create new product objects and map it.

```
var products = new List<Product>();
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(LOCAL))
{
  sqlConnection.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
  {
   cmd.CommandText = "select Sku from product;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) ????
   {
    var product = new Product();
    //Grab the values using the SqlDataReader and map it to the properties
    //...
    //Add code e.g. product.Id = reader.GetField<int>("Id");
    //...
    products.Add(product);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a list to store the products
2. Create each product from data in the DataReader
3. Add each product to the list

   ```
   var products = new List<Product>();

   using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) ????
   {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.Name = reader.Field<string>("Name");
        p.Sku =  reader.Field<string>("Sku");  
        // etc.
        products.Add(p);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these a simple ORM like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) is invaluable.
Let us suppose that your class `Product` is something like this and it mirrors the datatable on db

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Sku {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    ... and so on for the other fields ....
}
```

Now to get a `List<Product>` using Dapper you simply write

```
public List<Product> SelectAllProducts()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LOCAL))
    {
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS ORDER BY Name";
        return connection.Query<Product>(query, null).ToList();
    }
}
```